# Add style elements in CSS

Tags: javascript, css

I want to make my own custom CSS elements that will be handled by a js file of mine.  Is this possible?

Here would be an example:

```
div {
    rounded-corners:15px 15px
}
```

And then use Javascript to apply the styles for each browser for rounding corners.

Is there a way to do something like this?

**EDIT**

The point isn't to add a common support for browsers.  I want to implement my own CSS things.

Comment: You know there's already a CSS property for rounded corners, right? It's called `border-radius`.  Also, you might want to check out something like http://css3pie.com to save you the trouble of implementing rounded corners in unsupported browsers.

Comment: @AndyE: well, as far as I remember, browsers differ in how they support that property.

Comment: @Griwes: I seem to get consistent results where I use it.  Perhaps older versions of browsers with early implementations work differently.

Comment: What _exactly_ are you trying to achieve? There is high probability that the "CSS thing" you are trying to implement already exists.

Comment: Even with the edit you may need to give a different example.

Comment: re rounded corners (`border-radius`): there were some differences in early implementations, but that was quite a long time ago (Firefox 3.0); current versions of all browsers that support it are pretty much the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is "no".  While it is possible to easily get style values from stylesheets in Internet Explorer by accessing the `currentStyle` property, like so:

```
alert(myDiv.currentStyle['rounded-corners']);
//-> "15px 15px"
```

...other browsers don't support the `currentStyle` property, opting instead to support the W3C standard `window.getComputedStyle()`.  `getComputedStyle()` doesn't include "expando" style properties in the outcome, which means your only option would be to iterate over the rules in each stylesheet instead, which could be an expensive procedure depending on how many stylesheets and rules you have.  Obviously, you also lose out on the browser's cascading/computing.

Answer (score 0):

IE9 and the latest versions of Firefox and Chrome all handle border-radius anyway.

And you can use [CSS3 Pie](http://css3pie.com) to add support to older version of IE.  No need to write your own script.

EDIT: I suppose you could write your own version of CSS3 Pie, but why would you want to?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into [SASS/SCSS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/), which both offer "mixins". These act like functions in CSS, and should let you do what you want. LESS at least can be made to work client-side through Javascript; I suspect SCSS can too.

Answer (score 0):

CSS already has a property for rounded corners, called `border-radius`.

This is supported by virtually all browsers in current use. The only exception of any significance is IE8 and earlier.

The good news in this case is that IE8 *can* indeed be programmed to work the way you're asking. Other browsers cannot, but IE can, and this is lucky, as it's the one browser that needs it more often than most.

So the direct answer to your question is "sometimes". Most browsers drop the styles they don't support, but IE keeps them. It obviously don't do anything with them, but you can access them via the DOM, which means that you can do what you're asking.... but only really in IE.

In the case of rounded corners, there is already an excellent Javascript-based hack for it called [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/). This is open source, so you can examine their source code to learn how it's done.

The CSS3Pie code is quite complex though, so if you want a simpler example to work from, take a look at [this older script](http://www.htmlremix.com/css/curved-corner-border-radius-cross-browser) which does the same thing a lot more simplistically. Easier to read, but not as functional. For real life use, use CSS3Pie, but for learning, this one is a better starting point.

For working with IE, I would suggest following the examples in these scripts to achieve what you're asking. For other browsers, you will have a much harder time.